# select only projects where modified date in log_table is from the last 7 days in Sybase

Tags: sybase

I'm having a project table with no modify date and a logtable with changes on all tables. In the logtable you can have more than 1 record for 1 project (every time you change something a line is written in the logtable. I was trying to create a select query to have only the projects that are created/updated in the last 7 days.

Something is wrong in my query because I receive:

```
 'derived table Log1 has no name for column 2' SQLCODE=-163
```

My code:

```
select pr.projectid, 
       pr.projecttitle
from   project pr
inner
join   (select   row_ID, 
                 max(date_action)
        from     logtable_data 
        group by row_ID
        having   table_name = 'PROJECT'  
        and      max(date_action) > dateadd(day,-7,convert(Date, getdate(), 365))
       ) Log1
on     pr.projectid = Log1.row_ID
```

`-- table_name = 'PROJECT'` is for only have the changes of table `'PROJECT'` from the `logtable`

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is being used in a *join clause* so it's also referred to as a *derived table*.

A *derived table* must have a name for each of the columns/expressions in the `select` list.

The second column/expression - `max(date_action)` - does not have a name hence the error message.

A couple other issues:

- `table_name = 'PROJECT'` should be supplied as a *where* clause
- `getdate()` returns a date so there's no need to convert its results to `date`, ie, the `convert(Date,...)` is unnecessary. [**NOTE**: I'm also assuming the `date_action` column
  has a data type of `date` or `datetime`]

Pulling this all together:

```
select pr.projectid, 
       pr.projecttitle
from   project pr
inner
join   (select   row_ID, 
                 max(date_action) as max_action_date     -- 'as' clause used to name column
        from     logtable_data 
        where    table_name = 'PROJECT'                  -- limit data selection
        group by row_ID
        having   max(date_action) > dateadd(day,-7,getdate())
       ) Log1
on     pr.projectid = Log1.row_ID
```